# How to zip and save jSON data received from an API with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rails-activestorage

So, I'm creating an app that works like a bot, it makes a call to an API from time to time, then it receives a response in a json-like format and saves it like this:

```
    finalResult = RestClient.get( apiUrl, headers = apiHeaders )
    jsonData = JSON.parse(ActiveSupport::Gzip.decompress(finalResult))

    time = Time.now

    File.write("public/#{time}.json", jsonData)
```

I'm using ActiveSupport to be able to parse this Gzip compressed data, since it's a lot of data, otherwise it takes forever to get it. Then I get the time the data was received, basically, and I use it to name the file so that I can keep good track of it.

What I need to do now is compress this .json file, if possible, into a .zip file(it can be .rar, or .7z, or .tz, whatever) before I upload it to my storage so it takes less space. Is there anyway that I can do something similar to `File.write` but to save it as a zipped json file? I already checked stuff like zlib and ruby-zip, but they only let me zip files that already "exist", so I can't save it as a zipped .json directly, I'd need to take the .json file and then zip it, but how could I do that if the name of the file is a `Time.now` and it always change?

I'd appreciate any help, thanks in advance :)

**EDIT¹**

Giving some more details that may help you to help me:
I created a controller and model to handle this, since I'll be using ActiveStorage. It's ResponsesController and Response model, and the only parameter that the Response model has is `has_one_attached :json_file`. I intend to use Heroku to handle the CRON job of calling the API and I'll upload the .json files(or .zip files) to an AWS storage.

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to deal with the compression yourself. If your client uploading the data uses [HTTP compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) then the server will handle this for you automatically. As for saving, what library do you want to use? For JSON Gzip or Bzip is probably the best bet, especially with more aggressive compression settings.

Comment: Oh, okay, I'll change the names to the convention, but in this case(my code) it's just a matter of good pratice, right? I mean, it's working.

Comment: Yeah, it works, at least in this form.

Comment: What you mean I shouldn't need to deal with the compression myself? I'm a jr dev still in learning process, so I'm not familiar with a lot of stuff ): Sorry
The thing is, if I compress it again with gzip, using ```ActiveSupport::Gzip.compress```, ```File.write``` does not work

Comment: I also added some info in my question that may help you to help me

Comment: Have you tried adding a compression hook to your ActiveStorage configuration for this attachment?

Comment: No, after you commented it I even searched info about it, couldn't really find it.
What would that be?

Comment: I can only find examples dealing with re-compressing images, but I didn't dig too deeply. There's a pre-processing chain you can hook into for things like this.

Comment: Same, only found stuff about re-compressing images so far. I'll dig into what you just said, to be honest I didn't really understand what you meant, so I'll do some research. Thanks for the comments and your time!